# Want to create XML schema to validate two XMLS

Tags: wpf, xml, xsd

I have 2 Xml files. 1st file we can call master as its having all nodes and in 2nd files only few information is there.
How can i creat a single xsd supporting both files.

File1:

```
     <Information ID="08" >
<description>office information</description>
<officeName>SBV</officeName>
<A id="234"> 
    <name>xyz</name>
    < age>23</age> 
    <dept>SE</dept>
</A> 
<B id="244"> 
    <name>lkj</name>
    < age>27</age> 
    <dept>Sales</dept>
</B>
<C id="264"> 
    <name>opi</name>
    < age>34</age> 
    <dept>Manufacture</dept>
</C> 
<D id="774"> 
    <name>yui</name>
    < age>25</age> 
    <dept>Production</dept>
</D>
</Information>

File2:
    <Information >
<description>Worker information</description>
<A id="234"> 
    <name>xyz</name>
    < age>23</age> 
    <dept>WP</dept>
</A> 
<B id="244"> 
    <name>lkj</name>
    < age>27</age> 
    <dept>WP</dept>
</B>
</Information>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible schema - which should be considered as a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Information">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="officeName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="A">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="dept" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="B">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="dept" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="C">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="dept" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="D">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="dept" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In my case, I've used [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) to create the XSD automatically, by pointing it to the two XML documents you've posted.

This is what I've got (it validates both):

[image]

The next steps should then be to "rationalize" the generated XSD. For example, if you look at the content models of elements A, B, C and D, all share the same; if indeed this is the case, then you could have a global type declaration, basically reused. Or, it could be that C and D must appear in a "both or none" combination, in which case additional tweaking may achieve exactly that. Below is a manually amended schema, based on the above comments, to give you an idea on what it would look like. Keep in mind that **both** XSDs validate your XMLs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Information">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="officeName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="A" type="atype"/>
                <xs:element name="B" type="atype"/>
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element name="C" type="atype"/>
                    <xs:element name="D" type="atype"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="atype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="dept" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

By now, one can see that the latter is more compact in terms of "source". The content models though are quite similar.

[image]